# Logstash on Docker keeps running even with pipeline failure

Tags: logstash

In another words, how do I make sure Logstash dies when a pipeline fails to start?

I'm running Logstash 7.1.1 with 5 pipelines, calling each other using [pipeline-to-pipeline communication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html). When there's an error in starting one of the pipelines (e.g. syntax error), the error is simply logged which is easily missed.

Simplifying the problem to 2 pipelines:

```
[2019-07-04T17:48:47,887][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.1.1"}
[2019-07-04T17:48:56,393][ERROR][logstash.plugins.registry] Tried to load a plugin's code, but failed. {:exception=>#<LoadError: no such file to load -- logstash/filters/BADFILTER>, :path=>"logstash/filters/BADFILTER", :type=>"filter", :name=>"BADFILTER"}
[2019-07-04T17:48:56,423][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:myid, :exception=>"LogStash::PluginLoadingError", :message=>"Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'BADFILTER'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the BADFILTER filter plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/filters/BADFILTER", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/registry.rb:211:in `lookup_pipeline_plugin'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugin.rb:137:in `lookup'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:200:in `plugin'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:50:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:23:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-07-04T17:48:58,313][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"myid2", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x357de3fe@/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:37 run>"}
[2019-07-04T17:48:58,412][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"myid2"}
[2019-07-04T17:49:00,440][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

In this example, pipeline "myid" failed to start as I used a non-existent plugin BADFILTER, and "myid2" started fine. The process then keeps running and doesn't fail.

How can I configure Logstash to die if it can't start-up a pipeline? Follow-up question, how can I get Logstash to die if there's an error after successfully starting (e.g. lost connection to elastic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Logstash works when running with multiple pipelines, if at least one pipeline is correct the logstash process will run regardless if some pipelines are failing and it will keep trying to restart the failed pipelines if you enabled the automatic reload.

If you want to Logstash to stop if one of your pipelines fail, you will need to use only one pipeline and filter the data using tags and conditionals, which was the way to run multiple pipelines before the introduction of the pipelines.yml option.

Comment: I see... I wonder how people are using pipelines in production then. How would you know if there's an issue with a pipeline and you aren't accumulating or losing events that can't be processed?

Comment: You need to monitor your infrastructure, the basic license of the Elastic Stack allows you to have monitoring on Kibana where you can see your running pipelines and how many events per second each one is receiving, but there are a lot of monitoring tools available.

Comment: We do monitor our infra, the problem is that we have it in Kubernetes and logstash out-of-the-box isn't quite ready for K8s. Ideally liveness and readiness probes would hook into an endpoint that verifies all pipelines are working correctly but I don't think this exists. We use https://github.com/BonnierNews/logstash_exporter (part of https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/logstash) for exporting metrics to prometheus and maybe those metrics have enough data to proper monitor multi-pipelines. But then, if we had that in K8 it would hopefully handle things in a more automated way.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the regular expression you need in the stdout (example: **terminated**):

```
logstash | while read line ; do if [[ ${line} =~ terminated ]]; then $(kill -TERM $(pgrep -u logstash)); fi ; done
```

For my docker tests I run something similar to this:

```
docker run docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.10.1 /bin/bash -c 'sleep 2 && time logstash 2>&1 | while read line ; do if [[ ${line} =~ terminated ]]; then $(kill -TERM $(pgrep -u logstash)); fi ; done'
```